# Fail to install packages in RStudio

Tags: r, installation, r-package

I want to install package arulesViz but RStudio returned me this:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jacque de l'est/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘arulesViz’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/PACKAGES'
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I've tried to install other packages but fail too. Before everything was fine when I installed packages in RStudio

Comment: You must download and install [Rtools 4.0](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) before installing packages from source on Windows. But you don't have to install from source, there are binaries available for Windows packages. What is the command you ran to get those errors?

Comment: `install.packages("arulesViz")`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Try restarting R and see if the error goes away.

Comment: I guess `download.file("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES")` fails too, maybe because you are behind a proxy. See `Setting Proxies` in the help page `?download.file`

Comment: After download RTools and restart RStudio, it works again @MartinMorgan

Answer (score 0):

R needs [Rtools](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html) to build packages from source--just [download](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/) and install it. :)